# connection string connect mdb file in network with turn on password protected sharing

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, network-programming

how to connect ms access database in shared folder with password protected with my asp.net mvc 5 app
this my connection string

add name="DbKoneksiAbsensiHO" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\192.168.100.114\dbhris\HITFPTA.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=tes;User ID=admin"

it's run if i turn off password protected, but doesn't if turn on.
how to set username and password to my connection?
or how to set it to IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the folder as a shared folder to the web server and have the web server authenticate for folder access, the user and password in connection string is for the database. Or you can create a user for the folder that alows the IIS_User from your machine access to the folder.